# SQL 'AS' statement Error in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to do the following sql to return 3 latest blog details from MySQL database, though getting the error, what I am missing here?

```
SELECT   tblpost_id, 
         post_title, 
         img_url, 
         img_date, 
         post_catg, 
         'post_contentL' AS substr(post_content,1,23) 
FROM     tblpost 
ORDER BY tblpost_id DESC 
LIMIT    3
```

I tried in the sql command window and its giving me the error as

> #1064 - Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de 'SUBSTR(post_content,1,23) FROM tblge_post ORDER BY tblge_post_id DESC LIMIT 3' Ã  la ligne 1

and in the php I am trying the following code to display it, * all the mysql php retrieval objects are working fine.

```
$row['post_contentL']
```

Please help me to identify the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone! YES i reversed it!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the other way round. Substitute this:

```
'post_contentL' AS SUBSTR(post_content,1,23)
```

with:

```
SUBSTR(post_content,1,23) AS post_contentL
```

Answer (score 1):

`Alias` name should come after the `Column` name. You have *reversed* it

```sql
SELECT tblpost_id, 
       post_title, 
       img_url, 
       img_date, 
       post_catg, 
       Substr(post_content, 1, 23) AS `post_contentL` --here 
FROM   tblpost 
ORDER  BY tblpost_id DESC 
LIMIT  3
```

Comment: Thank you for amending the question :)

Answer (score 1):

it is not a valid query, `Alias` should be named after query functions

```
'post_contentL' AS SUBSTR(post_content,1,23)
```

should be with 'AS'

```
SUBSTR(post_content,1,23) AS 'post_contentL'
```

OR without `AS`

```
SUBSTR(post_content,1,23) 'post_contentL'
```